# Hand position sensor

Tags: sensors, prototype

What is the simplest way to get an alarm sound when a human raise hands up.
Assuming he is wearing a sensor or whatever as a watch or ring.

Comment: tilt sensor .......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tilt sensor, can be used as what you are trying to say, whenever someone (who wore it) raise his hand or move it, will trigger an alarm.

If you want to carry your alarm with you then...
You can use arduino nano or micro with a sensor and buzzer connected to it to just place it in gloves or watches etc.